# CNN model with matrix input and vector output shape question

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

This my first time coming across matrix input and vector output situation, some confusions here.

My required CNN structure shown as below:
[image]

Layer description is here:

[image]

The batch size is 200, thus input is a 2 * 24 matrix represented by `tensor(200*[2*list[]]`), expected output is 4 * 1 matrix represented by `tensor(200*[4*list[]])`, the model code I own so far:

```
class BNN_P1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BNN_P1,self).__init__()
        self.conv1=nn.Conv2d(1,8,kernel_size=3,stride=1,padding=1,bias=True) #layer 2, convolutional 
        self.bn1=nn.BatchNorm2d(8,eps=1e-03, momentum=0.99)       #layer 3,batch normalization
        self.conv2=nn.Conv2d(8,8,kernel_size=3,stride=1,padding=1,bias=True)  #layer 5,convolutional
        self.bn2=nn.BatchNorm2d(8,eps=1e-03, momentum=0.99)       #layer 7,batch normalization
        self.fc=nn.Linear(?,?)                                     #layer 9,fully connected
        self.sigmoid=nn.Sigmoid()                               #layer 10,sigmoid
        
    def forward(self,x):
        batch_size=x.size(0)
        x=F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(x)))              #layer 4,ReLU
        x=F.relu(self.bn2(self.conv2(x)))              #layer 6,ReLU
        x=x.view(batch_size,-1)                          #layer 8,flatten
        x=self.fc(x)
        x=self.sigmoid(x)
        
        return x
```

My question is how should I determine the linear input and output setting to get correct answer? If possible can someone explain me the shape changes during the process?

Comment: What is `N`, and `K`? Anyhow, I think I already answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68401275/6331369). For the number of outputs logits in your fully connected, the question is: *how many logits do you need?*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate dimensions of first linear layer of a CNN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68398528/how-to-calculate-dimensions-of-first-linear-layer-of-a-cnn)

Comment: N=6 and K=4, much thx for help, I will check these posts, btw the question yesterday I use the simpler nested lists and has been solved, anyway thx your patience

Comment: *"btw the question yesterday"* which question was it?

Comment: Convert to tensor given a list of 'list of array'